# How to tell which process is hogging network resources through OpenVPN (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, networking, openvpn, network-traffic, resource-usage

Sometimes I detect that some process is downloading a lot of data (it actually uses the maximum speed that my mobile connection can get), and when I try to check it with Task Manager or Process Explorer, I see that the traffic belongs to the openvpn.exe process, but I can't get any more information besides that.

So I know that it is VPN traffic instead of direct internet traffic, but nothing more. I check which network connections that process has open, and it only shows the HTTPS connection that the VPN client in my PC establishes to the remote VPN server.

How can I know which other process on the PC is downloading the data through OpenVPN?

Comment: Are you running a VPN server on your computer?

Comment: @harrymc No, only a client

Comment: So why do you say that some other computer is using your bandwidth? The server cannot initiate anything on your computer.

Comment: @harrymc I rephrased it. It's not other computer, it's some program in my PC that is downloading something through the VPN, but I can't tell which program is it

Answer (score 1):

**(1)I suggest you start with Windows Resource Monitor. (Windows Admin Tools) and also Task Manager.**

This will let you see network usage by App / Process.

Let it run for 15 minutes or thereabouts and see what App is using all the network resource.

You can also use Task Manager to see some additional details of network usage.

**(2) You can also use Nirsoft AppNetworkCounter** to get additional details on network usage. Look for process that (by name) might be related to Open VPN. You can right click on the name and see properties which might help.

**(3) Then you can use SysInternals, Process Explorer to see what is running under another process.**  In the screen shot, you can see what vmware_authorization is running . This may help you with Open VPN.

Then (more difficult) Windows Admin Tools, Performance Monitor allows you to add measurement sets to help show what is spawning a process. More complicated.

[image: Windows Resource Monitor]

[image: Nirsoft Counter]

[image: SysInternals Process Explorer]

Comment: The poster already did this - the result will be openvpn.exe.

Comment: I added some significant clarification to try to assist.

Comment: @golimar I tried to present numerous possibilities, including SysInternals Process Explorer which can show process under another process. This may help you

Answer (score 1):

If a process is downloading at full speed, there will be other indications.

Start the Task Manager, go to the Details tab, right-click the headers
and click "Select columns".

Add indicators, and especially "I/O reads" and "I/O writes", and also
"CPU time". Click a column to sort it in descending order.
Watch the indicators change while data is downloading, in order to
identify the process that is doing this.